# ESLint wrongly indents single-return statement of multiline param JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, return, eslint, multiline

I have this function with multiline parameters and single-body return (because they're long). This is a plain JS file:

```js
const myFunction = (
    looooooooongParam1,
    looooooooongParam2,
    looooooooongParam3,
    looooooooongParam4,
) => (
    looooooooongParam1
    + looooooooongParam2
    + looooooooongParam3
    + looooooooongParam4
    + looooooooongParam4
);
```

ESLint formatting wrongly shifts the returned lines to the right. Then it complains that the indentation is wrong (sure it is!):
[image]

My ESLint rules are:

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2020: true,
    },

    extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'airbnb',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],

    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',

    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 11,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },

    plugins: [
        'react',
        '@typescript-eslint',
    ],

    rules: {
        'react/jsx-filename-extension': [2, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
        'react/jsx-indent': ['error', 4],
        indent: ['error', 4],
        'import/extensions': [
            'error',
            'ignorePackages',
            {
                js: 'never',
                jsx: 'never',
                ts: 'never',
                tsx: 'never',
                mjs: 'never',
            },
        ],

        'no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    },

    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            node: {
                extensions: [
                    '.js',
                    '.jsx',
                    '.ts',
                    '.tsx',
                ],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

I use VSCode and format with eslint on save. VSCode related settings:
[image: VSCode screenshot]

Any ideas how to make ESLint keep the return lines to the left?

***Edit 1:** when saving the file in VSCode, I see the code correctly indented for like 0.2 seconds then it becomes incorrectly indented.*

***Edit 2:** if I have less params, on a single line, indentation works fine, so **this happens only when having multiline params;**.*

Comment: Looks like you have rules for both `jsx-indent` and `indent`. Maybe they interfere with each other?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so, because my function is inside a plain JS file and contains no JSX (I edited to include that is a JS file)

Comment: are you using prettier? If then disable it and try again.

Comment: @PramodMali Nope, no prettier installed at all. This happens when function params are placed on multiple lines. Somehow that forces the function body to go to the right.

Comment: Can you try overriding this rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/function-paren-newline with "function-paren-newline": ["error", "never"]. Maybe one or more of the 'recommended extends' are causing this to happen.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help but I found the issue: I tested manually eslint --fix on the file and it worked fine, so I found VSCode has it's own formatter and was overlapping what ESLint was doing - I had to do `"javascript.format.enable": false`. Same applies to TSX files, I had to do `"typescript.format.enable": false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I manually ran `eslint --fix` on the file, I noticed it worked fine, so I found that *VSCode has it's own formatter and was overlapping what ESLint was doing*.

**Solution:** I had to do `"javascript.format.enable": false` to disable VSCode's JS formatter formatting my JS files to let only ESLint do it.

Note: same story applies to TSX files, I had to do `"typescript.format.enable": false` to let only ESLint format TSX code.